# How do I calculate a line from a series of points?

Tags: algorithm, image-recognition

Probably an easy question, but I could not find an easy solution so far. I'm working on a simple image recognition software for a very specific use case.

Given is a bunch of points that are supposedly on a straight line. However, some of the points are mistakenly placed and away from the line. Especially near the ends of the line, points may happen to be more or less inaccurate.

Example:

```
   X            // this guy is off
         X      // this one even more
 X              // looks fine
 X
  X
      X         // a mistake in the middle
  X
     X          // another mistake, not as bad as the previous
   X
    X
   X
    X
         X      // we're off the line again
```

The general direction of the line is known, in this case, it's vertical. The actual line in the example is in fact vertical with slight diagonal slope.

I'm only interested in the infinite line (that is, it's slope and offset), the position of the endpoints is not important.

As additional information (not sure if it is important), it is impossible for 2 points to lie next to each other horizontally. Example:

```
   X
   X
    X
   X X   // cannot happen
    X
     X
```

Performance is not important. I'm working in C#, but I'm fine with any language or just a generic idea, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear regression (as mentioned by others) is good if you know you do not have outliers.

If you do have outliers, then one of my favorite methods is the median median line method:
http://education.uncc.edu/droyster/courses/spring00/maed3103/Median-Median_Line.htm

Basically you sort the points by the X values and then split the points up into three equal sized groups (smallest values, medium values, and largest values).  The final slope is the slope of the line going through the median of the small group and through the median of the large group.   The median of the middle group is used with the other medians to calculate the final offset/intercept.

This is a simple algorithm that can be found on several graphing calculators.

By taking the three medians, you are completely ignoring any outliers (either on the far left, far right, far up, or far down).

The image below shows the linear regression and median-median lines for a set of data with a couple of large outliers.

[image: Linear Regression vs. Median-Median]

Comment: I like this answer. But if this would to be solved with the least square method I think you should weight the points so that the ones at the ends doesn't weigh as much as the ones in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [Least squares fit via Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)

Comment: Thanks, good idea! Is there a way to use the idea of excluding points that are clearly mistakes?

Comment: My idea would be use first calculate the roughly correct line per the method you linked, then to repeatedly remove the points that are the furthest away from the line until all points are close to the line. Does this make sense, or is there a better way?

Comment: you could calculate the line of best fit, then check how far each point is from the line.  points above a certain threshold could be identified and then you could calculate a new line of best fit without using the points you considered to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea, too. Great, I think this is going to work. Thankies!

Comment: @mafutrct, as long as you are sure that you can reject points that lie on the same horizontal axis, I would remove those before calculating the regression line... that way it is not polluted with questionable data... are those situations unusual in your data?  If you can't use this method, I would agree with @Sam Holder

Comment: @Mike: It is physically impossible to occur due to the way I calculate the points.

Answer (score 3):

Mike is spot on! Use the following:

```
double[] xVals = {...};
double[] yVals = {...};

double xMean = 0;
double yMean = 0;
double Sxy = 0;
double Sxx = 0;
double beta0, beta1;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < xVals.Length; i++)
{
   xMean += xVals[i]/xVals.Length;
   yMean += yVals[i]/yVals.Length;
}

for (i = 0; i < xVals.Length; i++)
{
   Sxy += (xVals[i]-xMean)*(yVals[i]-yMean);
   Sxx += (xVals[i]-xMean)*(xVals[i]-xMean);
}

beta1 = Sxy/Sxx;
beta0 = yMean-beta1*xMean;
```

Use beta1 as the slope and beta0 as the y-intercept!

Comment: +1 This works, I'll leave the accepted answer over at Mike though since he showed the basic idea.